# establish connection from python to matlab

Tags: python, matlab, udp, data-transfer, real-time-data

I am trying to transfer data in real time from python to matlab using UDP protocol (as this post suggested: [Real-time data transfer from Python to MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027046/real-time-data-transfer-from-python-to-matlab)).

right now this is what I have, and it dosent work:

on python (sender):

```
import socket

my_socket= socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8821))

MESSAGE='test1'
for i in range(1,10):
    my_socket.send(MESSAGE)
    print i

my_socket.close
```

on matlab (reciver):

```
u = udp('0.0.0.0','LocalPort',8821);
fopen(u);

while(1)
    A = fread(u,10);
end

fclose(u)
```

It dosent work, and the errors I get:
from python:
[image]

and from matlab:

```
Warning: Unsuccessful read:  The specified amount of data 
was not returned within the Timeout period.
```

any idieas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me if I actually tell `socket` that I want a UDP connection:

```
my_socket= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

(hat tip to https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication)